# Trying to make pagination work with .htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I was pretty proud of myself because for the first time ever, I actually figured out how to update the .htaccess file without asking for help (a new milestone for me).

Here's what I added:

```
RewriteRule albums/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ albums.php?language=$1&searchindex=$2&searchparameterdata=$3
```

that worked to translate my links to:
    www.my domain.com/albums/en/music/beatles/

But then.. along came pagination and I'm stumped again.  On clicking my next page, it now appends to the above url like such..

```
beatles/?language=en&locale=us&page=2&searchindex=music&searchparameter=keywords&searchparameterdata=beatles&
```

Is this something I can correct in my .htaccess..  keeping the format of my working url and still letting pagination work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making it too hard for yourself; why not send all parameters *in a single parameter* and let php decide what to do with it? Try this:

```
RewriteRule albums/(.*) albums.php?parameters=$1 [L]
```

And then in your php:

```
parse_str($_GET['parameters], $parameters);
do_stuff($parameters['searchindex'], $parameters['page'], ...);
```

nice and easy :)

check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php for the manual on `parse_str()`, `do_stuff()` is obviously invented ;)

Comment: Oh wow.. what a GREAT idea!  Thanks so much!  This is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag to your RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule albums/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ albums.php?language=$1&searchindex=$2&searchparameterdata=$3 [QSA]
```

Also, you might want to check your pagination link themselves. My guess is the query string is actually a part of the pagination href. If that's the case, then I can't think of any easy way to remove the query string via the mod-rewrite. You will need to modify your pagination links so that the href only includes the querystring parameters that you want. In this case, the only query string parameter you will want is the `page=2` portion.